# How to style a control inside a border with a corner radius

Tags: wpf

I have a simple window containing an outer border with a corner radius, and an inner border with a background. The border is basically just a placeholder for any type of content I would like to place inside the rounded corner outer border.

```
<Window x:Class="TestRunner.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" AllowsTransparency="True" 
        WindowStyle="None" Background="{x:Null}" >
    <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="8"  >     
           <Border Background="White">

           </Border>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

The problem is that the inner control does not inherit the rounded corner so it draws on top of the rounded corner, like this:

[image: Bad corner rendering]

How do I adjust my outer control, so inner controls do not attempt to draw on top of the rounded corner.

Setting rounded corner on the inner control is not a viable option as it will lead to horrible duplication of corner radius.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming that you have a `Border` within a `Border` just to illustrate the problem. If possible, just avoid the issue altogether by not including any control within the outer `Border` that renders anything in the corners.

If you *must* include a control that renders something in the corners, you could use a `Clip`:

```
<Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="10">
    <Border.Clip>
        <RectangleGeometry Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=border}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=border}" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10"/>
    </Border.Clip>

    <Border Background="White"/>
</Border>
```

Another option (depending on your exact scenario) might be to place the outer `Border` "above" the other content. As long as it has a transparent `Fill` and `IsHitTestVisible` set to `false`, it may be sufficient:

```
<Grid>
    <Border Background="White"/>
    <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3" Fill="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="false"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

`RectangleGeometry` does not have a `Width` property, at least in WPF.

For my needs, I had to create a `IMultiValueConverter` as described here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5650367/2663813

After that, I still had a problem at the corners, so I used Kent's second solution (Note that `Border.Fill` doesn't exist either).

Here is a what I wrote:

```
<Grid>
    <Border x:Name="canvasBorder" CornerRadius="5">
        <Border.Resources>
            <tools:ContentClipConverter x:Key="ContentClipConverter" />
        </Border.Resources>
        <Border.Clip>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ContentClipConverter}">
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth"
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                <Binding Path="ActualHeight"
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                <Binding Path="CornerRadius"
                RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Border.Clip>
        <!-- ... -->
    </Border>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Background="Transparent" IsHitTestVisible="false" />
</Grid>
```

and inside the ContentClipConverter.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Clips the content of a rounded corner border.
/// Code taken from <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/5650367/2663813">this topic</a>
/// </summary>
public class ContentClipConverter : IMultiValueConverter {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a clipping geometry for the item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="values">The input values</param>
    /// <param name="targetType">The parameter is not used.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">The parameter is not used.</param>
    /// <param name="culture">The parameter is not used.</param>
    /// <returns>The clipping geometry</returns>
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        if (values.Length == 3 && values[0] is double && values[1] is double && values[2] is CornerRadius) {
            var width = (double)values[0];
            var height = (double)values[1];

            if (width < double.Epsilon || height < double.Epsilon) {
                return Geometry.Empty;
            }

            var radius = (CornerRadius)values[2];

            // Actually we need more complex geometry, when CornerRadius has different values.
            // But let me not to take this into account, and simplify example for a common value.
            var clip = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), radius.TopLeft, radius.TopLeft);
            clip.Freeze();

            return clip;
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Not implemented
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value">The parameter is not used.</param>
    /// <param name="targetTypes">The parameter is not used.</param>
    /// <param name="parameter">The parameter is not used.</param>
    /// <param name="culture">The parameter is not used.</param>
    /// <returns>This function does not return anything</returns>
    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to put some padding on the outer border:

```
<Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="8" Padding="4">
    ....
</Border>
```

but this might lead to too much white space in your application.