# Border contents escapes even when using ClipToBounds & CornerRadius

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

I have a custom control that sits inside a border, the border has a `CornerRadius` and an inner shadow that should create a nice look. Inside that border is a custom Control but that control seems to ignore the border radius and makes it look square when the control is placed underneath a corner.  How can I fix this?

```
<Border Background="#ccc" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" ClipToBounds="True" CornerRadius="5">
    <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Gray"  ClipToBounds="True" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0">
        <Grid>
            <Toolkit:CanvasControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"> 
            <!-- more contents here -->
            </Toolkit:CanvasControl>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

The `CanvasControl` is defined as so

```
public class CanvasControl : Panel
{
}
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5650367/124386)?

Comment: That would have been amazing, but it has to work in silverlight too and that doesnt support `IMultiValueConverter` :/

Comment: No I am actually wrong, I don't need this for Silverlight and you are my hero!

Comment: Incidentally, if you do need MultiBinding for Silverlight: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/286171/MultiBinding-in-Silverlight-5