# Clipping a border in WPF

Tags: wpf, clipping, clip, opacitymask

I need to create a round `ProgressBar` template.

ControlTemplate :

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
   <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">                      
     <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" Margin="1" Fill="White" />

     <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1"  >
        <Grid x:Name="Foreground" >
            <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
            <Grid x:Name="Animation" ClipToBounds="true" >
               <Rectangle x:Name="PART_GlowRect" Fill="#FF86C7EB" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-100,0,0,0" Width="100"/>
            </Grid>                             
        </Grid>                                                             
     </Border>

     <Border x:Name="roundBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
             BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="10" />
     <TextBlock />

  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This results in :

[image: image of incorrect clipping]

Where `PART_Indicator` is the LightBlue rectangle on the left (its width is set internally in the `ProgressBar` control, as seen here with a value of 20) and the `roundBorder`.

What I need is for the the `PART_Indicator` to clip over the `roundBorder`, resulting in something like:

[image: image of desired clipping]

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649875/wpf-how-to-make-the-border-trim-the-child-elements) question. It may help you

Comment: BY THE WAY for any one looking at this question. The answer below. sadly with the 0 up votes on it. Works great. it is the way to go. no converters. no additional influence on the template based on stuff from the control. 
simple clipping while preserving.

Comment: @gt which one ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A much better solution using an OpacityMask , All The Template Parts aside from the OuterBorder Placed in "MainGrid" are Clipped using an Opacity mask which is set by an object aside it called "MaskBorder".

"TemplateRoot" exist for the inner workings of the PrograssBar control.

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot">
            <Border x:Name="OuterBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="10">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="MaskBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="9.5" />

                    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
                        <Grid.OpacityMask>
                            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=MaskBorder}" />                                   
                        </Grid.OpacityMask>

                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" Fill="White" />

                        <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left">                                 
                            <Grid x:Name="Foreground">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                                <Grid x:Name="Animation" ClipToBounds="true">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_GlowRect" Fill="#FF86C7EB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-100,0,0,0" Width="100" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>                                                                   
                    </Grid>                                                                                                                                     

                </Grid>                         
            </Border>                       
        </Grid>                      
   </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Hi @Sheridan , i found a much better solution then the one i had.

Answer (score 7):

There is a `ClipToBounds` property on the `Border` class that *should* clip the content at the bounds of the `Border`, but unfortunately, it doesn't 'do what it says on the tin':

```
<Border CornerRadius="25" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" BorderThickness="3" Width="300" 
    Height="50" ClipToBounds="True"> <!-- This doesn't work as expected -->
    <Rectangle Fill="SkyBlue" />
</Border>
```

However, the `Rectangle` class also provides some properties that could help. Is there something stopping you from just using the `Rectangle.RadiusX` and `Rectangle.RadiusY` properties to round the `Rectangle` corners?:

```
<Border CornerRadius="25" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" BorderThickness="3" Width="300" 
    Height="50">
    <Rectangle RadiusX="23" RadiusY="23" Fill="SkyBlue" />
</Border>
```

I'm aware that you want to clip the coloured fill of the `Rectangle`, but you could use the `Rectangle.Clip` property for that:

```
<Border CornerRadius="25" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" BorderThickness="3" Width="300" 
    Height="50">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Name="ClipRectangle" Fill="Green" Margin="50,0,0,0" 
            Visibility="Hidden" />
        <Rectangle RadiusX="23" RadiusY="23" Fill="SkyBlue" Clip="{Binding 
            RenderedGeometry, ElementName=ClipRectangle}" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

This clips the coloured `Rectangle` with the `RenderedGeometry` of the other `Rectangle` named `ClipRectangle`... or when I say *this clips*, perhaps I should have said *this is supposed to clip* as I've just discovered that this only appears to work in the WPF Designer and not when the application is run.

[image]

However, I'm out of time here, so hopefully you can find the final piece of the puzzle and complete this yourself. Potentially, you could also complete this by data binding to the `GradientStop.Offset` property of a `LinearGradientBrush` that is set as the `Background` on the `Border`, so you wouldn't even need a `Rectangle` for this method. I'll have another look if I can later.

---

UPDATE >>>

I had another look at this `Clip Rectangle` and can't work out why it only works in the Visual Studio Designer. So, giving up with that idea, you can try the `LinearGradientBrush` idea instead, which is equally good. First, define your `Brush`:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ValueBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="SkyBlue" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="SkyBlue" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="Transparent" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Transparent" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

For now, I've hardcoded the values in to produce this:

[image]

From just this code:

```
<Border CornerRadius="25" BorderBrush="RoyalBlue" Background="{StaticResource 
    ValueBrush}" BorderThickness="3" Width="300" Height="50" ClipToBounds="True" />
```

For your actual requirements, you'd need to create a `double` property to data bind to the `GradientStop.Offset` property like this:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ValueBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
    <GradientStop Offset="0.0" Color="SkyBlue" />
    <GradientStop Offset="{Binding MidPoint}" Color="SkyBlue" />
    <GradientStop Offset="{Binding MidPoint}" Color="Transparent" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1.0" Color="Transparent" />
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Now, as long as you provide a value between 0.0 and 1.0, this will create your level meter.

Comment: I actually couldn't get it to work , i'll try it later 
+1 min-while

Answer (score 3):

What i ended up doing :

ControlTemplate :

```
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">

                    <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Track" Fill="White" />

                    <Border x:Name="roundBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="10"/>

                    <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left">

                        <Border.Clip>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{x:Static common:UIConverters.BorderClipConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="roundBorder" />
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="roundBorder" />
                                <Binding Path="CornerRadius" ElementName="roundBorder" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Border.Clip>

                        <Grid x:Name="Foreground">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Indicator" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                            <Grid x:Name="Animation" ClipToBounds="true">
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_GlowRect" Fill="#FF86C7EB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-100,0,0,0" Width="100" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                </Grid>             
      </ControlTemplate>
```

BorderClipConverter : ( from [Marat Khasanov answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649875/wpf-how-to-make-the-border-trim-the-child-elements) ) with some fine tuning in the Rect

```
public class BorderClipConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length == 3 && values[0] is double && values[1] is double && values[2] is CornerRadius)
        {
            var width = (double)values[0];
            var height = (double)values[1];

            if (width < Double.Epsilon || height < Double.Epsilon)
            {
                return Geometry.Empty;
            }

            var radius = (CornerRadius)values[2];

            var clip = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(1.5, 1.5, width - 3, height - 3), radius.TopLeft, radius.TopLeft);
            clip.Freeze();

            return clip;
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```