# How to make a rounded Border and Background colour exactly fit the text extents in a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got the following XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Level}"/>
</Grid>
```

`Level` is basically a log level (`Verbose`, `Information`, `Warning`, `Error`).

First I would like to add a background colour but only to the text itself.

If I do `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Level}" Background="Yellow"/>` then I end up with something like this:

`Verbose`

I can workaround that by doing the following:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="{Binding Level}" Background="Yellow"/>
</TextBlock>
```

And now I correctly end up with:

`Verbose`

But now I would like to round the corners of just the text itself, and that ... I can't find a way to do and would appreciate some help with.

I've tried adding a `Border` to the `TextBlock` but that creates a border around the whole `TextBlock`, not just the text inside it.

Comment: What about setting an ``HorizontalAlignment`` to your `TextBlock?` It will prevent it from stretching to its parent size (here, an oversized grid column).

Comment: You can set the width of first column to `Auto`, e.g. `<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>` to auto width column according its content

Comment: That works for the `TextBlock` itself, but if I add a `Border` and set the `Background="Yellow` to the `Border` (and also `CornerRadius="10"` or so) then it will again take up the whole grid column.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski setting it to `Auto` will also cause it to potentially take up more space than what I want it to (it won't truncate values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set an `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment` on a `FrameworkElement` like a `Border` or `TextBlock`, it will prevent it from stretching to its parent size (which is the [default behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment?view=netframework-4.8#property-value)).

You can write the following XAML:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Yellow" CornerRadius="5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

And the `Border` only takes the space needed to fit its child `TextBlock`.

Comment: Absolute correct answer, just need to wait a few minutes before accepting it xD

Comment: If you want to later clip the border so the background does not spill out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158147/clipping-a-border-in-wpf