# C# WPF Custom Progressbar with CornerRadius, problem of Clip

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, clip

I want to make a custom ProgressBar(with CornerRadius) control ,My thought is using 2 borders(1:border,2:indicator),So I can set the same CornerRadius,but something wrong with the clip.
I did clipping the indicator,but it will overflow the border,here is my code

### The xmal code:

```
<Border x:Name="PART_Border"
                            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Border.Clip>

                            <MultiBinding Converter="{convertors:BorderClipConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                                <Binding Path="CornerRadius" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Border.Clip>
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
```

### The cs Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace AirControl
{
    public class AirProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(AirProgressBar),
                new PropertyMetadata(default(CornerRadius)));

        public new static readonly DependencyProperty IsIndeterminateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsIndeterminate", typeof(bool), typeof(AirProgressBar),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), PropertyChangedCallback));

        public new static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value", typeof(double), typeof(AirProgressBar),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(double), ProgressValueChanged));

        private static void ProgressValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var airProgressBar = d as AirProgressBar;
        }

        private Border border;
        private Border indicator;

        static AirProgressBar()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AirProgressBar),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(AirProgressBar)));
        }

        public AirProgressBar()
        {
            SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                DoAnimation();
                CalcWidth();
            };
        }

        public double Value
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(ValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }

        public new bool IsIndeterminate
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsIndeterminateProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsIndeterminateProperty, value);
        }

        public CornerRadius CornerRadius
        {
            get => (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
            set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
        }

        private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var airProgressBar = d as AirProgressBar;
            airProgressBar?.DoAnimation();
            airProgressBar?.CalcWidth();
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            border = (GetTemplateChild("PART_Border") as Border)!;
            indicator = (GetTemplateChild("PART_Indicator") as Border)!;
        }

        private void CalcWidth()
        {
            if (IsIndeterminate)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (border is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Value = Math.Max(0d, Value);
            var percentage = Value / 100;
            indicator.Width = ActualWidth * percentage;
        }

        private void DoAnimation()
        {
            if (IsIndeterminate is false)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (border is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            indicator.Width = ActualWidth / 4;
            Storyboard sb = new() { RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            var thicknessAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation
            {
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(6000)),
                From = new Thickness(-indicator.Width, indicator.Margin.Top,
                    indicator.Margin.Right, indicator.Margin.Bottom),
                To = new Thickness(Width, indicator.Margin.Top,
                    -indicator.Width, indicator.Margin.Bottom)
            };
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(thicknessAnimation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));
            sb.Children.Add(thicknessAnimation);
            sb.Begin(indicator);

        }
    }
}
```

### The converter Code:[Click me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5650367/11728446)

### The problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### I fix it:

> I found out that I should put 2 boders in a Grid,then set the Grid's Clip.The out border determine Progressbar's size, the inner border is the indicator.

#### here is the repo：

- [AirProgressBar.cs](https://github.com/nieshaoju/Air/blob/master/AirControl/AirProgressBar.cs)
- [AirProgressBar.xaml](https://github.com/nieshaoju/Air/blob/master/AirControl/AirProgressBar.xaml)

#### CS:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Automation;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace AirControl
{
    public class AirProgressBar : ProgressBar
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(CornerRadius), typeof(AirProgressBar),
                new PropertyMetadata(default(CornerRadius)));

        public new static readonly DependencyProperty IsIndeterminateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "IsIndeterminate", typeof(bool), typeof(AirProgressBar),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), PropertyChangedCallback));

        public new static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value", typeof(double), typeof(AirProgressBar),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(double), ProgressValueChanged));

        private static void ProgressValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var airProgressBar = d as AirProgressBar;
            airProgressBar.CalcWidth();
        }

        private Border border;
        private Border indicator;

        static AirProgressBar()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AirProgressBar),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(AirProgressBar)));
        }

        public AirProgressBar()
        {
            SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                DoAnimation();
                CalcWidth();
            };
        }

        public double Value
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(ValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }

        public new bool IsIndeterminate
        {
            get => (bool)GetValue(IsIndeterminateProperty);
            set => SetValue(IsIndeterminateProperty, value);
        }

        public CornerRadius CornerRadius
        {
            get => (CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);
            set => SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);
        }

        private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var airProgressBar = d as AirProgressBar;
            airProgressBar?.DoAnimation();
            airProgressBar?.CalcWidth();
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            border = (GetTemplateChild("PART_Border") as Border)!;
            indicator = (GetTemplateChild("PART_Indicator") as Border)!;
            if (border.CornerRadius is { } radius && radius.TopLeft >= 1)
            {
                indicator.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(CornerRadius.TopLeft - BorderThickness.Left, CornerRadius.TopRight - BorderThickness.Top,
                    CornerRadius.BottomRight - BorderThickness.Right, CornerRadius.BottomLeft - BorderThickness.Bottom);
            }
        }

        private void CalcWidth()
        {
            if (IsIndeterminate)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (border is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Value = Math.Max(0d, Value);
            var percentage = Value / 100;
            indicator.Width = border.ActualWidth * percentage;
        }

        private void DoAnimation()
        {
            if (IsIndeterminate is false)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (border is null)
            {
                return;
            }

            indicator.Width = ActualWidth / 4;
            Storyboard sb = new() { RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
            var thicknessAnimation = new ThicknessAnimation
            {
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000)),
                From = new Thickness(-indicator.Width, indicator.Margin.Top,
                    indicator.Margin.Right, indicator.Margin.Bottom),
                To = new Thickness(Width, indicator.Margin.Top,
                    -indicator.Width, indicator.Margin.Bottom)
            };
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(thicknessAnimation, new PropertyPath("Margin"));
            sb.Children.Add(thicknessAnimation);
            sb.Begin(indicator);
        }
    }
}
```

#### XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AirControl"
                    xmlns:convertors="clr-namespace:AirControl.Convertors">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Colors.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:AirProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MainBackground}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainForeground}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DefaultBorderBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:AirProgressBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Grid">
                        <Grid.Clip>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{convertors:ClipConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                <Binding Path="CornerRadius" ElementName="PART_Border" />
                                <Binding Path="BorderThickness" ElementName="PART_Border"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Grid.Clip>

                        <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
                            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                        </Border>
                        <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="PART_Border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be mistakes caused by not taking into account the `BorderThickness` of outer `Border` properly.

1. Regarding the left side of bar, the corner radius of inner `Border` should be smaller than that of outer `Border`. That said, the corner radius of inner `Border` seems unnecessary because inner `Border` is supposed to be clipped anyways.
2. Regarding the right side of bar, you miscalculated the width of inner `Border`. You need to decrease it by the value of `BorderThickness` of outer `Border`.

Although I am not sure what is your intension behind, I would suggest the following modifications.

The converter originally created by Marat Khasanov can be modified to utilize `BorderThickness` as well so as to be used for inner `Border`.

```cs
public class BorderInnerClipConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values is { Length: 4 } &&
            values[0] is (double width and >= double.Epsilon) &&
            values[1] is (double height and >= double.Epsilon) &&
            values[2] is CornerRadius radius &&
            values[3] is Thickness thickness)
        {
            var rect = new Rect(0, 0, (width - thickness.Left - thickness.Right), (height - thickness.Top - thickness.Bottom));
            var radiusX = radius.TopLeft - thickness.Left;
            var radiusY = radius.TopLeft - thickness.Top;

            var clip = new RectangleGeometry(rect, radiusX, radiusY);
            clip.Freeze();

            return clip;
        }

        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Then the ControlTemplate for AirProgressBar would be as follows.

```xml
<local:BorderInnerClipConverter x:Key="BorderInnerClipConverterKey"/>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="AirProgressBarTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:AirProgressBar}">
    <Border x:Name="PART_Border"
            CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Border x:Name="PART_Indicator"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
            <Border.Clip>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BorderInnerClipConverterKey}">
                    <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="PART_Border"/>
                    <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="PART_Border"/>
                    <Binding Path="CornerRadius" ElementName="PART_Border"/>
                    <Binding Path="BorderThickness" ElementName="PART_Border"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Border.Clip>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Finally, while there are several unclear parts in your csharp code, CalcWidth method would be as follows.

```cs
private void CalcWidth()
{
    if (IsIndeterminate)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (border is null)
    {
        return;
    }

    Value = Math.Max(0d, Value);
    var percentage = Value / 100;
    indicator.Width = (border.ActualWidth - border.BorderThickness.Left - border.BorderThickness.Right) * percentage;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but not suit me, I found a better solution: [ClippingBorder](https://github.com/SonyWWS/ATF/blob/8044bc01dbe0522cab65762960b6b58681c8dce0/Framework/Atf.Gui.Wpf/Controls/ClippingBorder.cs)
 it's not perfect but enough for me, if you have wondering about my code, here is my repo:
[Air](https://github.com/nieshaoju/Air)